# How to disable "RewardedVideoAd" closing while the ad is not finished?

Tags: java, android

I started to get interested in Google mobile ads. Right now I am testing `RewardedVideoAd` functionality with Google given testing ad. Everything works fine, but **I can't find the way how to disable ad closing while the ad is not finished.**
Below is my abstract code which shows how I am using the `RewardedVideoAd` method:

```
public class TestPage extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {


    private Button button;
    private final static String APP_ADMOB_ID = "[my_app_admob_id]";
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ADMOB_ID);
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

        loadRewardedVideoAd();

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video ad loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video ad opened",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video ad started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + rewardItem.getType() + "  amount: " +
                rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Left app during video ad",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load video ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now, when ad video is displayed user can press back button and then appears dialog box with message: *`Close video?`*. I want to disable this ability.
But I don't know how it could be done. I tried to `@Override` `onBackPressed()` method and inserted if statement with checks boolean value if it is able to do something or not. But it does not work.
So my main question is:
**Is there any way to disable ad closing while video is running?**
Thank you for any type of help.
*P.S.: I have read all "AdMob for Android" instructions and I don't need link of it.*

Comment: Im pretty sure this is on purpose and there is no way to disable this easily. You are not supposed to force users to watch an add without letting them close it unless they force kill the app. you are just supposed to show them the ad and if they close if before it ends you dont give them the reward.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Maybe user have to decide himself to look it or not. Than it would be more comfortable for users. As I have tried other apps, there is type of ability. Somehow developers disabling to close the ad unless you kill the app. But they the AdMob is using on Unity, so it could be it have more features there. I will think about your offer. Thank you.